# Zonal statistics error in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I'm trying to get the zonal statistics output (mean), do some operations and add to my main archive the output value. I wrote this code, but it's not running, the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\04 - Temp\Charles\NDVI_tempo\NDVI_py3.tbx#Script3_NDVIpy3.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 6328, in ZonalStatistics
    ignore_nodata)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 6321, in Wrapper
    ignore_nodata)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 506, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
Failed to execute (Script3).
```

---

```
import arcpy
import os
import datetime
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#Declarar as variáveis

arcpy.env.workspace = 'Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL_PL'
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("test*", "All")
fc = 'Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL_PL\\MA02ASEZ3S'
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

for tiff in rasters:
#Zonal statistics
    Zonaltif = ZonalStatistics(fc, ["ID_TALHAO"], tiff, "MEAN")
    Zonaltif.save('Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL_PL\\teste')
    Zonalper = Times (Zonaltif, 100)
    Zonalint = Int (Zonalper)
    RasterToPolygon_conversion (Zonalint, Zonalpoly, "SIMPLIFY", "VALUE")
    Intersect_analysis ([Zonalpoly, fc], 'Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL_PL\\teste\\intertif', "ALL", "", "")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A few suggestions that may help. You have spaces in your directory paths which can still cause problems in some functions. In your `ZonalStatistics` function the syntax for the zone field should not contain `[ ]`. I don't see where you have defined `Zonalpoly` that is used in the `RasterToPolygon_conversion` function.

Comment: Now the error is: ERROR 000865: Input raster or feature zone data: Z:\04 - Temp\Charles\NDVI_tempo\NAL_PL\MA02ASEZ3S does not exist.
ERROR 001000: Zone field: Field ID_TALHAO does not exist
Failed to execute (ZonalStatistics).
Failed to execute (Script3).

It's like it don't recognize the feature

Comment: You also need to add the `.shp` extension to the feature `MA02ASEZ3S`.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting spaces in output file directory worked in my case. Thanks!